# How to JSON Data (hash) containing arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json

I'm trying to find a way to sort JSON data in ruby.  It's stored as a fairly complicated (I think so anyway) hash that looks like this:

```
{
    "allergies": {
        "allergy": [
            {
                "id": "11426793",
                "name": "Milk",
                "category": "Food Allergy",
                "createdPerson": "AGUDELO-HERNANDEZ  ARCADIO",
                "onsetDate": "2014-05-05T00:29:28-04:00"
            }, {
                "id": "11426788",
                "name": "Antibiotics",
                "category": "Drug Allergy",
                "createdPerson": "Smith John H",
                "onsetDate": "2014-05-04T22:29:28-04:00"
            }
        ]
    },
    "responseErrors": {
        "responseError": []
    }
}
```

There's a lot more "Allergy" objects that exist in the actual data, and I want to be able to sort them by the "onsetDate" then by "name".  I've tried:

```
sorted = @allergies["allergies"].sort_by { |hsh| hsh["name"] }
```

but I get the following error:

```
no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
require "json"

str = <<EOS 
 {
  "allergies": {
    "allergy": [
    {
      "id": "11426793",
      "name": "Milk",
      "category": "Food Allergy",
      "createdPerson": "AGUDELO-HERNANDEZ  ARCADIO",
      "onsetDate": "2014-05-05T00:29:28-04:00"
   },
   {
     "id": "11426788",
     "name": "Antibiotics",
     "category": "Drug Allergy",
     "createdPerson": "Smith John H",
     "onsetDate": "2014-05-04T22:29:28-04:00"
   }

]
},
"responseErrors": {
  "responseError": []
}
}
EOS

@allergies = JSON.parse(str)
puts @allergies["allergies"]["allergy"].sort_by { |hsh| hsh["name"] }
```

You have JSON (not hash), so you first have to parse it from JSON into hash. Also, the array you are trying to sort is 2 levels deep.

Answer (score 0):

`@allergies["allergies"]` returns a hash, which is:

```
{
    "allergy": [
        {
            "id": "11426793",
            "name": "Milk",
            "category": "Food Allergy",
            "createdPerson": "AGUDELO-HERNANDEZ  ARCADIO",
            "onsetDate": "2014-05-05T00:29:28-04:00"
        }, {
            "id": "11426788",
            "name": "Antibiotics",
            "category": "Drug Allergy",
            "createdPerson": "Smith John H",
            "onsetDate": "2014-05-04T22:29:28-04:00"
        }
    ]
}
```

Calling `sort_by` on a hash, it will yield each key-value pairs to the block. So in

```
@allergies["allergies"].sort_by { |hsh| hsh["name"] }
```

`hsh` is an array. `Array#[]` expects Integer as its argument. It will try to convert `"name"` to Integer, and fails with the error you seen.

You need

```
@allergies["allergies"]["allergy"].sort_by { |hsh| hsh["name"] }
```

or, if you want to sort the values in place, so that the original data will have sorted `allergy`, use `sort_by!`